# how to add new node in Running Solr cluster with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrcloud

I am new to Solr Cloud and I have setup of 3 Solr instance and 3 ZooKeeper in my local machine for testing purpose. Now I would like to add new Solr node to that cluster without restarting/reinstalling Solr tomcat services. Solr instances are running on port 8081,8082,8083 and zookeepers are running on 2181,2182,2183. Now I would like add new instance on port 8084. So what will be the efficient way to add it and will I need to use one more zookeeper on port 2184 or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just point your new solr node to the existing zookeeper setup when you start it. That will be enough.

Comment: Hey Binoy, Thanks for your answer.How many zookeepers are required for 3 machines, either 3 or more?what is efficient number of zookeepers?

Comment: The production config is at least 3-5 zookeeper instances. The idea is to always have an odd number to maintain the quorum.